# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json in my Spring boot app using DataTables

Tags: jquery, json, spring, spring-boot, datatable

Following [this](https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-jquery-datatables-a2e816e2b5e9) tutorial, I am using Data Tables in a spring boot app. 
This is my Rest Controller:

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(path="user/users", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<User> getAllUsers(){
    return userService.getAllUsers();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "user/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUsersById(@PathVariable("id") long id){
    return userService.getUserById(id);
}
```

And this is datatable.js

```
  $(document).ready( function () {
 var table = $('table#employeesTable').DataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "/user/users",
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "id"},
          { "mData": "name" },
              { "mData": "lastName" },
              { "mData": "email" }

        ]
 })
   });
```

There's User Entity, Service and Repository as in the tutorial. 
But when launching the application and going to user/users , I do not get the DataTable with the results but I get them in JSON format and I also get the warning :

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "localhost:8080/user/users"
```

Is there anything I should change in the controller or the javascript code, or anywhere else so that these results are on the Table ?
Instead it won't even show the html file with its design, only the data collected from the db. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working as expected.

I believe you are try to access the application using url:

```
localhost:8080/<context-path>/user/users
```

`<context-path>` is in most cases the name of your web application

This will invoke the Rest Controller you have written.

To view the table you have to hit:

```
localhost:8080/<context-path>
```

This loads the Controller i.e `EmployeeController.java` form the tutorial and loads the view.

There is no view attached to the Rest Controller.

Comment: Oh God! I hadn't even noticed I had placed the html file in the same path I was trying to get the results.
Thank you soooo much !!!!